# Listing directory with hiden files first and grouping directories

Tags: bash, ls

I'm trying to compose a command/function to list any directory displaying the files with the following rules, from top level to deepest level:

1. hidden files
2. directories
3. alphabetically

Another feature I want to grant is to be able to use the command/function for a passed directory. Example:

## Goal

Basically I'd like to input something like:

```
user@machine:cuur-path $ my_listing_magic /some/crazy/directory
```

and get an output looking like:

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 User Group 4,0K abr  8 12:12  .aaa_dir/
drwxrwxr-x  3 User Group 4,0K abr  8 12:12  .bbb_dir/
drwxrwxr-x  3 User Group 4,0K out 14  2020  .ccc_dir/
-rw-rw-r--  1 User Group 4,1K abr 12 17:44  .a_file
-rw-r--r--  1 User Group   25 dez  4  2017  .b_file
-rw-rw-r--  1 User Group   21 mai 20 15:50  .c_file
drwx------ 44 User Group 4,0K mai 27 16:44  ddd_dir/
drwx------  3 User Group 4,0K abr  5  2018  eee_dir/
drwx------  3 User Group 4,0K abr  5  2018  fff_dir/
-rw-r--r--  1 User Group 4,8K jun  1 18:52  d_file
-rw-r--r--  1 User Group 1,2K jun  1 19:42  e_file
-rw-------  1 User Group 106K jun  1 19:33  f_file
```

(note that the directories `.` and `..` are not there.)

## Failed Atempts

### Just use `ls` options

The closest I've gotten is `ls -alhvF --group-directories-first`. It is almost there, but doesn't respect the desired order and keeps both `.` and `..`. I coulld strip those out *a posteriori*, but since the ordering is not correct, there is no point.

`ls -lv` namely the `-v` is nice as it sorts all the `.files/dirs` up alphabetical.
`ls -l --goups-directories-first` is also cool, does what is expected. To bad I can't make it 'act before' the `-v`.

### Divide and Conquer

I though of splitting up the problem into two: I could first list the hidden files and then the not hidden: `list_hidden; list_non_hiden`. Then for simplicity of usage I could create an alias or function to call them in proper order.

The non-hidden is quite trivial! But listing solely the hidden files is becoming a bit more troublesome. I tried something like `ls -ld .!(|.)`, but this has the drawback of using `-d` - so it cannot be used to list some other directory. At least not without having the full path of the file there...

Thanks!

Comment: In short `find .... | sort | xargs ls`. I do not think you can make ls add / on the directories. You can always write your own ls in C - why use shell. `any thought please let me know` This is not a forum for "any thought" - it's a question&answer forum for programming problems. What specific problem are you struggling with? What _question_ do you want to ask. Please peek at [ask]. For a forum with "thought" check out other forums - quora, reddit, etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thanks for the pathway!
Sory about being nice, I'll just removed the line. Hope it makes the "Goal" and the problems with my atempts more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The `ls` utility does not support what you want. So implement it yourself. List the files, then sort them, then `ls` them, yourself. A script that uses zero-terminated stream and GNU coreutils and findutils could look like the following:

```
{
     printf "%s\0" . ..;
     cmd=(
        find "${1:-.}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 '('
            -name '.*' '('
               -type d -printf "1 %p\0"
            ')' -o 
                -printf "2 %p\0"
        ')' -o '('
             '!' -name '.*' '('
                 -type d -printf "3 %p\0"
            ')' -o
                 -printf "4 %p\0" 
        ')'
     )
     "${cmd[@]}" |
     sort -z |
     cut -z -d' ' -f2-;
} | xargs -0 ls -ald
```

You can patch some open-source `ls` utility with your own behavior - it would be nice and I am in favor of implementing it inside GNU coreutils `ls` as yet another option like --sort-hidden-directories-first to sort them in front of hidden files.

You can also write your own `ls` utility in C (or you could reimplement `ls` in shell, but I suspect It would be harder then just writing it in C).

---

Because I liked the idea for a long time and wanted to have hidden files sorted before anything else, I created [this l utility](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/-/blob/master/bin/l) that uses the method described above.